# llvm : lower 3 operands to 2 operands instruction

Tags: llvm, operand

Currently llvm's add, sub,... instructions require 3 operands : `dest`, `src1`, `src2`.

*How can I write a custom "add" instruction that only supports 2 operands ?*
Eg : `dest = dest + src1`.

I tried this in the .td file, but it didn't work :

```
defm Reg: Instr<opcode, (outs RC:$dest), (ins RC:$A),
              !strconcat(opcodeStr, " $dest, $dest, $A"),
              [(set Ty:$dest, (opNode Ty:$dest, Ty:$A))]>;
```

It complains that "Input operand $dest occurs in pattern but not in operands list!"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to model it as 3-operand instruction, but add a constraint that one of source operands equals to destination. See X86 backend as an typical example how to do this.